# How to Stretch Bitmap into Parent Panel (wxWidgets Custom)

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

[Screenshot of Panel and a custom inside of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhYrH.png)

I set a wxButton and it loads bitmap,png formats to Panel at right. But image is overfitting. I want to stretc image to Panel when it's loaded by button.

Here is button's function, just in case:

```
void rrFrame::testClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxBitmap bmp;
    wxString strPath = wxT("img\\img1.png");

    bmp.LoadFile(strPath, wxBITMAP_TYPE_ANY);
    camFrame_wx->DrawBitmap(bmp, wxPoint(0, 0), false);
    //camFrame_wx is the variable name of 'Custom'
}
```

I suppose i need a stretch or fit function in constructor. How to do this?

Comment: @RIrudezu, you can either try to use extra panel or use wxBitmapButton. Check the samples of how the sizers works and do something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to load the image file into a [wxImage](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_image.html) first, then rescale the wxImage, and finally convert the wxImage to a wxBitmap.  Like so:

```
void rrFrame::testClick(wxCommandEvent& event)    
{
    wxString strPath = "img\\img1.png";
    wxImage im(strPath,wxBITMAP_TYPE_ANY );
    wxSize sz = camFrame_wx->GetSize();
    im.Rescale(sz.GetWidth(),sz.GetHeight(),wxIMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH );
    wxBitmap bmp(im);
    camFrame_wx->DrawBitmap(bmp, wxPoint(0, 0), false);
    //camFrame_wx is the variable name of 'Custom'
}
```

Two additional comments:

1. You shouldn't need the wxT macro for string literals in [wxWidgets 3.0 or later](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_changes_since28.html).
2. You can use other options such as wxIMAGE_QUALITY_NEAREST instead of wxIMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH if you need faster rescaling.  The full list is available [here](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/image_8h.html#a8cb59f5925c96a706710106f679d171a).